# How to remove window icons on the top right of VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code has tons of options to customise the interface, but I can't figure out how to remove those pesky window icons on the top right: those buttons that open the sidebar and bottom bar. Is this possible?

[image: vscode]

Comment: search the settings for `layout`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution: you need to right click on it and select hide control layout, it will remove the windows icons.

Answer (score 1):

Top left corner in Visual-Studio-Code, Open **file** => **Preferences** => **settings** than click on the top right side **Open Settings (JSON)**

[image]

And You need to add to your `settings.json` this line:

```
"editor.renderControlCharacters": false,
```

[image]